# Showing a .gif animation in QLabel

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, animated-gif

I would like to show a .gif animation in a `QLabel` widget, alongside text.

The following code won't work:

```
self.status_txt = QtGui.QLabel('Loading... <img src="etc/loading.gif">')
```

as the image won't animate.

I tried achiving it by using a `QMovie` object:

```
self.status_txt = QtGui.QLabel("Loading...")
movie = QtGui.QMovie("etc/loading.gif")
self.status_txt.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()
```

But then I can't put the animation and the text together.
Is there a different solution besides using two different labels?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can add a Layout to the label, and then add another Label with the text to that...

```
self.status_txt = QtGui.QLabel()
movie = QtGui.QMovie("etc/loading.gif")
self.status_txt.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()
self.status_txt.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
self.status_txt.layout().addWidget(QLabel('Loading...'))
```

*edit*:

it's possible if you use your own version of a QLabel and a QPainter to paint the text yourself:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel, QMovie, QPainter, QFontMetrics

class QTextMovieLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, fileName):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        self._text = text
        m = QMovie(fileName)
        m.start()
        self.setMovie(m)

    def setMovie(self, movie):
        QLabel.setMovie(self, movie)
        s=movie.currentImage().size()
        self._movieWidth = s.width()
        self._movieHeight = s.height()

    def paintEvent(self, evt):
        QLabel.paintEvent(self, evt)
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setFont(self.font())
        x = self._movieWidth + 6
        y = (self.height() + p.fontMetrics().xHeight()) / 2
        p.drawText(x, y, self._text)
        p.end()

    def sizeHint(self):
        fm = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        return QSize(self._movieWidth + 6 + fm.width(self._text),
                self._movieHeight)

    def setText(self, text):
        self._text = text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    l = QTextMovieLabel('Loading...', 'loading.gif')
    l.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I want the image to show right after the text, like it's a part of it.

Comment: then the easiest way is probably to use a widget with a QHBoxLayout and a QLabel and the QMovie side by side.

Answer (score 3):

Short, to the point answer:

```
movie = QtGui.QMovie('file.gif')
my_label.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()
```

Note that the import statement in this case is `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` which is the default generated by Qt Designer.

Comment: This indeed seems as best solution as of 2022 so far because it is short and straight to the point. The other accepted answer seems to go more in depth but can possibly be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that there is not possible way to use the same widget for this job. Two different QLabels must be used.