# Using a gif in Splash Screen in pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, splash-screen

I am new to gui designing with pyqt..
I want to use a gif in the splash screen.. using this code..

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, time

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and display the splash screen
    splash_pix = QPixmap('a.gif')
    splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    #splash.raise_() 
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()

    # Simulate something that takes time
    time.sleep(2)

    form = Form()
    form.show()
    splash.finish(form)
    app.exec_()
```

But i am getting only the first frame of the gif...How do i overcome this...?

Comment: This may help.  They use a QLabel and QMovie.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261265/showing-a-gif-animation-in-qlabel

Comment: @wbt11a The link is for displaying a .gif in the application .. but i want to add that .gif to the splash screen and I am not able to add a QLabel or a QMovie to the splash screen

Comment: @Srinath. Animated gifs won't work at all using `QPixmap` - it can only display static content, which is why you only see the first frame. So you will either have to show a series of images in a loop, or use a widget that can display dynamic content, such as `QMovie`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')

class MySplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, animation, flags):
        # run event dispatching in another thread
        QSplashScreen.__init__(self, QPixmap(), flags)
        self.movie = QMovie(animation)
        self.connect(self.movie, SIGNAL('frameChanged(int)'), SLOT('onNextFrame()'))
        self.movie.start()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onNextFrame(self):
        pixmap = self.movie.currentPixmap()
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())

# Put your initialization code here
def longInitialization(arg):
    time.sleep(arg)
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, time

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and display the splash screen
#   splash_pix = QPixmap('a.gif')
    splash = MySplashScreen('a.gif', Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
#   splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    #splash.raise_()
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()

    # this event loop is needed for dispatching of Qt events
    initLoop = QEventLoop()
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(longInitialization, [2], callback=lambda exitCode: initLoop.exit(exitCode))
    initLoop.exec_()

    form = Form()
    form.show()
    splash.finish(form)
    app.exec_()
```

Note, that you need to run your initialization code in a separate thread, since the main thread should dispatch Qt events.

Comment: A few questions: What do you mean by "Put your initialization code here"? What type of code would go there? Also, my animation is freezing for a few seconds before the program opens up, any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBourbeau same here

Answer (score 1):

Translated into PySide:

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui

from multiprocessing import Pool

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')

class MySplashScreen(QtGui.QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, animation, flags):
        # run event dispatching in another thread
        QtGui.QSplashScreen.__init__(self, QtGui.QPixmap(), flags)
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(animation)
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.onNextFrame)
        #self.connect(self.movie, SIGNAL('frameChanged(int)'), SLOT('onNextFrame()'))
        self.movie.start()


    def onNextFrame(self):
        pixmap = self.movie.currentPixmap()
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())

# Put your initialization code here
def longInitialization(arg):
    time.sleep(arg)
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, time

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and display the splash screen
#   splash_pix = QPixmap('a.gif')
    splash = MySplashScreen('a.gif', QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
#   splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    #splash.raise_()
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()

    # this event loop is needed for dispatching of Qt events
    initLoop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(longInitialization, [2], callback=lambda exitCode: initLoop.exit(exitCode))
    initLoop.exec_()

    form = Form()
    form.show()
    splash.finish(form)
    app.exec_()
```