# How to display image (Transparent) without border at the time of program startup in Python

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence, display

I am working on a project, it is almost complete, i am working on it's gui.
i want to show a transparent image for 5 sec while starting the program in python

Comment: Which GUI library are you using?

Comment: I am using Tkinter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a splash screen, thats what the transparent image is called,

You can use pyQt to do this, it can be done via the code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    splash_pix = QtGui.QPixmap('img_name.jpg')
    splash = QtGui.QSplashScreen(splash_pix, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.show()

    def login():
        splash.close()
        if Login().exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            global window
            window = Main_Window()
            window.show()
        else:
            app.quit()

    show_time = 5000 # time in seconds * 1000 (milliseconds), hence 5 seconds = 5000 ms
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(show_time, login)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code is originally by [Splash screen in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930030/splash-screen-in-pyqt)

Could not flag it as duplicate due to lack of accepted answer, please accept this so this can be done for the future

In terms of functionality it works, i have used it before

Comment: I am new to this PyQt module can you pls provide me the code for tkinter module and also the import lines are not present,

Comment: I added these three lines  `from PyQt5.QtGui import *`
`from PyQt5.QtCore import *`
`import sys` but got error, this is error: `NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined`