# PyQt - Displaying GIF While Other Function Runs

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have an app that saves data to a file, and sometimes the save function takes quite awhile since my file is large. I wanted to have a "loading.gif" displayed while the file is being saved, but haven't figured out how to do so. Here is my code:

```
def saveBook(self):
    self.loadingWidget.setHidden(not root.journal.status.loading.isHidden())
    app.processEvents()
    self.excelSheet.save(filename = self.file)
    self.loadingWidget.setHidden(not root.journal.status.loading.isHidden())
```

LoadingWidget is the QLabel holding the GIF (which is automatically turned on).

- The first line turns the visibility of the GIF on
- The second line processes/displays the GIF immediately
- The third runs the save function (for however long)
- The fourth line turns the GIF back off.

The GIF is displayed, but it's paused. If I omit the fourth line, the GIF will play after the save function is finished, but I can't make the GIF play *while* the save function is running. How do I go about doing this?

Edit: Suggested duplicate is incorrect. That person was trying to display the gif alongside a label. I'm trying to have the GIF frame play while another function, `save`, runs. The GIF is already visible, but the app is not processing its playing until after the current `save` function is done.

Update - Solution:

```
def saveBook(self):
    #Show GIF
    root.saved.gif.on()
    #Update frame
    GLOB.app.processEvents()
    #Save on separate thread to allow interface to remain active
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.saveThread)
    t.start()

def saveThread(self): #this function runs in background, allowing GIF to run in main thread
    #Prevent multiple threads from queueing to save the file
    if not self.lock.acquire(False):
        return
    self.b.save(self.file)
    #Remove GIF
    root.saved.gif.off()
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing a .gif animation in QLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261265/showing-a-gif-animation-in-qlabel)

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate. That person was trying to display the gif alongside a label. I'm trying to have the GIF frame play while another function runs. The GIF is already visible, but the app is not processing it's playing until *after* the current function is done.

Comment: It's the same problem, the gif will only play if you place it inside a `QMovie` and then set that on the `QLabel`.

Comment: The gif is *already* inside a `QMovie ` and is hooked up to the `QLabel`. Line 1 makes the GIF appear, but it is paused. If I remove Line 4 (which hides the GIF), then the GIF will play, but only **after** the `saveBook` function is complete. This is an issue of getting to my GIF to run when I first make it appear, not after the function is completed.

Comment: @shivavelingker I'm having a similar problem at the moment. Were you, by any chance, able to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: @dliv Yes, I was. After `app.processEvents()`, I create a thread that points to the save function. When the save function completes, it turns off the GIF. Code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI won't update while QT is processing other code in the main event loop.  Generally, when you have long-running processes that you don't want to block the GUI, you would push those operations into a separate thread.